# Is an anchor tag without the href attribute safe?

Tags: html, hyperlink, standards, anchor

Is it okay to use an anchor tag without including the `href` attribute, and instead using a JavaScript click event handler? So I would omit the `href` completely, not even have it empty (`href=""`).

Comment: I think in most of the browsers (atleast in Firefox), the link will not be clickable without a href...

Comment: Semantically speaking it is not ok, but if you wish to do it, nobody is stopping you. The question is, why would you wish to do it? why not jusst use a span/div/p/whatever tag... if you don't need the href, why use the a tag?

Comment: The onclick event still triggers though? I want to use anchor tags instead of span/div because it is the only reasonable tag that supports CSS :hover in IE

Comment: @Martin ANCHORS can be accessed and activated via the keyboard. Regular SPAN elements cannot. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/4DTxv/2/

Comment: @ŠimeVidas, [`<span>` elements most certainly **can** be navigated via the keyboard](http://jsfiddle.net/4DTxv/10/). [You could also make it so that `<a>` elements are **not** navigable via keyboard](http://jsfiddle.net/4DTxv/11/).

Comment: @zzzzBov Ah, of course. I must have forgotten about `tabindex`.

Comment: In HTML5, anchors without href attribute are placeholder hyperlinks: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a button instead? This would mean that tabbing etc works, and you can style your buttons to look like links if necessary. Admittedly I don't know about hover in IE.

Comment: @IgnacioLago thanks for providing the a real explanation with the official doc: its licit in html5, the norm tells it

Answer (score 243):

In HTML5, using an `a` element without an `href` attribute is valid. It is considered to be a "placeholder hyperlink."

Example:

```
<a>previous</a>
```

Look for "placeholder hyperlink" on the w3c anchor tag reference page: https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element.

And it is also mentioned on the wiki here:
https://www.w3.org/wiki/Elements/a

A placeholder link is for cases where you want to use an anchor element, but not have it navigate anywhere. This comes in handy for marking up the current page in a navigation menu or breadcrumb trail. (The old approach would have been to either use a span tag or an anchor tag with a class named "active" or "current" to style it and JavaScript to cancel navigation.)

A placeholder link is also useful in cases where you want to dynamically set the destination of the link via JavaScript at runtime. You simply set the value of the href attribute, and the anchor tag becomes clickable.

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10510353/19112
- http://www.html5in24hours.com/2012/06/8-ways-to-get-started-with-html5-today/
- http://webdesign.about.com/od/html5tutorials/qt/html5-placeholder-links.htm

Comment: What is the definition of a "placeholder link"?

Comment: Take note that without an `href` the `cursor: pointer` style will not be automatically added to the element.

Answer (score 37):

My advice is use <a href="#"></a>

If you're using JQuery remember to also use:

```
.click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Click code here...
});
```

Comment: I cannot use href="#" because I am using ajax bookmarking which involves changing the hash, what can I do?

Comment: Hey, what is a non Jquery (plain JS) equivalent of ".click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // Click code here...
});
"

Comment: Instead of using javascript:void(0); inside the href I use javascript:; it's shorter to write.

Comment: The performance penalty only applies if you actually specify an empty href attribute. The question states there is no href attribute at all.

Comment: I would do onclick="return false;"

Comment: Actually, according to the article (and it makes sense) the potential performance penalty only applies for empty **src** attributes. It doesn't say anything about performance-wise about empty href attributes.

Comment: Jquery doesn't seem to target the a tag unless there is a href?
eg the title only gets applied  on the second anchor.  $('h3 a').attr('title', 'test'); <a name="test">Tuesday:</a><a href="test">Tuesday:</a>

Comment: Hello @Gunnar, the link seems to be gone now. Do you have another reference for the claim?

Comment: How abuot <a href>anchor</a>

Comment: href="#" will cause scrolling to top issues

Comment: Your advise is wrong: https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.0/href-no-hash

Answer (score 32):

If you have to use href for backwards compability, you can also use

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>
```

instead of # ,if you don't want to use the attribute

Comment: I needed an <a> tag that behaved like a link in all except function. This did the trick for me.

Answer (score 24):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

First, without an href attribute, it will not be a link. If it isn't a link then it wont be keyboard (or breath switch, or various other not pointer based input device) accessible (unless you use HTML 5 features of `tabindex` which are not universally supported). It is very rare that it is appropriate for a control to not have keyboard access.

Second. You should have an alternative for when the JavaScript does not run (because it was slow to load from the server, an Internet connection was dropped (e.g. mobile signal on a moving train), JS is turned off, etc, etc).

Make use of [progressive enhancement](https://web.archive.org/web/20160330201653/http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) by [unobtrusive JS.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

Comment: The problem is, I want something I can attach a click event to with jQuery's "click" method, that also gets highlighted and underlined like a link when the mouse rolls over it.  What else, besides an href-less anchor tag can accomplish that with no CSS? (i.e. as-is without manually adding that basic interaction, while retaining the simplicity of a direct click function assignment via jQuery).

Comment: @Triynko — Use a link, but do it properly. See the last line of the answer.

Comment: Tabindex on 'a' tags has been valid since HTML4 (at least) http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Comment: @technoTarek — Yes, but `href` was mandatory (unless it was a named anchor in which case tabindex didn't make sense). The use of `tabindex` to add unfocusable elements to the tab order is a new innovation in HTML 5.

Comment: @michael — The question says "safe" not "valid". I justified why it was unsafe, and everything I said then is still true.

Comment: It's not unsafe.  If you're worried about keyboard navigation you can set `tabindex` like technoTarek already stated.  You're also wrong stating `href` is mandatory.  Directly from the HTML4 spec it states: "Authors may also create an A element that specifies no anchors, i.e., that doesn't specify href, name, or id."  Creating an anchor without an `href` attr is (1) perfectly valid HTML, (2) perfectly safe, (3) useful in several situations.  I won't comment any further, but your answer is simply wrong.. At the very least, concede your "short answer" is extremely misleading.

Comment: @michael — It is unsafe. Depending on the JS to successfully run is still unsafe. I will conceed that my comment about href being mandatory was wrong.

Comment: @michael — "If you're worried about keyboard navigation you can set tabindex like technoTarek already stated" — You mean like I mentioned in the answer when I wrote it over half a decade ago?

Comment: As for "concede your "short answer" is extremely misleading" … the entire point of putting a long answer is to provide context for the short answer.

Comment: `tabindex` is not an HTML5 feature.  Using an `a` element without an `href` attribute is valid HTML4.  Using a `tabindex` attribute on said element without an `href` attribute is also valid HTML4.  Your "long answer" with "context" is equally as wrong as your "short answer."  I fail to see what you're not understanding.  If someone comes to this page and sees your answer, they're going to walk away with an incorrect understanding and more importantly an answer that's simply wrong.  Anyways, comments aren't for long discussions, so my apologies for even replying.  I won't be replying further.

Comment: @michael — "tabindex is not an HTML5 feature" I never said it was.

Comment: @michael — "Using an a element without an href attribute is valid HTML4" — I didn't claim that it was in the answer, and I have already said that the earlier comment I made was wrong on that point.

Comment: @michael — You keep agreeing with me while claiming that I'm wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117265/discussion-between-michael-and-quentin).

Answer (score 13):

The  tag is fine to use without an href attribute. Contrary to many of the answers here, there are actually standard reasons for creating an anchor when there is no href. Semantically, "a" means an anchor or a link. If you use it for anything following that meaning, then you are fine.

One standard use of the a tag without an href is to create named links. This allows you to use an anchor with name=blah and later on you can create an anchor with href=#blah to link to the named section of the current page. However, this has been deprecated because you can also use IDs in the same manner. As an example, you could use a header tag with id=header and later you could have an anchor pointing to href=#header.

My point, however, is not to suggest using the name property. Only to provide one use case where you don't need an href, and therefore reasoning why it is not required.

Comment: I think what the question was trying to ask and what the other answers are addressing, is whether it's safe to omit the `href` attribute for an `<a>` element *that's being used as an interactive element* (i.e. a link). As you mention, without an `href` attribute it's quite simply... not a link, just an anchor, which is a different thing altogether.

Comment: Yep, but - just to emphasize - the <a> tag is still valid in these use cases.

Answer (score 12):

From an accessibility perspective `<a>` without a href is not tab-able, all links should be tab-able so add a `tabindex="0"` if you don't have a href.

Comment: Or use a button if it's going to perform an in-page action instead of a redirection.

Comment: @SimonDever My CSS framework doesn't style buttons the same way as links, so this may be a no-go for some.

Answer (score 8):

The `<a>` tag without the "href" can be handy when using multi-level menus and you need to expand the next level but don't want that menu label to be an active link. I have never had any issues using it that way.

Comment: Have you tried accessing that menu with the keyboard?

Comment: I just found out that on IE, if you hover over some links and one is an anchor without href, the small popup with the URL below stays there, showing the previous url, instead of disappearing. The anchor is not clickable though, so it's not big issue, but enough for me to go with a div instead.

Answer (score 2):

In some browsers you will face problems if you are not giving an href attribute. I suggest you to write your code something like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="yourcode();return false;">Link</a>
```

you can replace yourcode() with your own function or logic,but do remember to add return false; statement at the end.

Comment: I'm using Backbone.js with Backbone.Router and have `#` for the index page.  For some of my navbar links I don't want to trigger a route to `#` which is what happens if you use `a href="#"` by itself. Using `<a href="#" onclick="return false;"` stops the route being triggered but the click event still bubbles up to my handler (which uses DOM events hooked via jQuery and Backbone.Radio).  Thanks @shashwat13 :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add bellows code in your working component on top to remove this warning, that's it.

/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */