# ngView disappears when navbar dropdown is clicked

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, ngroute, ng-view

I am trying to implement a page that contains a navbar (http://getbootstrap.com/components/ see navbar), and the content of the page is inserted from a partial html via ngView. However when the dropdown is clicked, the entire ngView portion disappears.

This is how I defined the ngView:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/l8GVWUiq2HRL3lXhu9xd?p=preview
(Please open by clicking "Launch preview in separate window" to see the navbar)
Click the navbar button "Dropdown".

If I debug the screen I can see that the ngView is not rendered at all, all I see is this:

```
<!-- ngView:  -->
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add this to the ul tag:

```
ng-click="$event.preventDefault();"
```

Comment: Follow up on this: although the navbar menu click now works, the menu item click does not do any routing. See updated plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/l8GVWUiq2HRL3lXhu9xd?p=preview

Comment: Basically, you don't want to forbid routing for all links, so just use $preventDefault properly. I added another view for the action route at [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WMLjaNDNq0KKoX4ZRmNK?p=preview) Here are some resources that could be useful for you: [official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route), [phonecat example](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat/blob/master/app/js/app.js)

Comment: I see - I took your advice literally and put it into <ul>. It should be added to the <a> under <li class=dropdown">. Thanks again!

Comment: It's such a bad practice to add $preventDefault for each li (this's just a quick fix) Instead, You can handle views by using router properly :)

Comment: im not making a navbar or anything. But I also have ng-view div compiling into <!-- ngView: --> and can't find any documentation on that. Did you ever get that answer?

Comment: That comment should be generated by the framework. If your routes didn't work as expected, see if $routeProvider was configured properly. This may help: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView

Comment: yup! You were correct, <!-- ngView --> only shows when there is no view to load. Found out that once again I forgot the () at the end of my self invoking function.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `href="#"` attribute from your `<a>` element in the dropdown link button and it will stop interfering in your routing.

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Comment: This works perfectly on html5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292343/is-an-anchor-tag-without-the-href-attribute-safe.