# Changing button border when active

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I have a couple action buttons that have a hover over effect.  When a button is clicked and active though, I want the button border to show and have the color change.  Ideally I would like to achieve this with pure CSS, but have tried without success.  Is this possible?  I've tried using the :focus and :active pseudo classes and nothing has worked.  Here is my code for my buttons:

```css
 .action-buttons {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      margin-top:2.75em;
    }
    
    .button {
      position: relative;
      padding: 10px 16px;
      font-size: 18px;
      width: 20rem;
      background-color: transparent;
      color: $color-lightest;
      text-align: center;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .button:before, .button:after {
      display: block;
      content: " ";
      border-top: none;
      border-right: none;
      border-bottom: none;
      border-left: none;
      position: absolute;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .button:before {
      top: -0.15rem;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .button:after {
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
    
    .button.at_the_same_time:hover:before {
      width: 20rem;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
      border-top: .5rem solid $color-lightest;
      border-right: .5rem solid $color-lightest;
      transition: width 300ms cubic-bezier(0.07, 0.62, 0.61, 1), height 150ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.07, 0.62, 0.61, 1);
    }
    
    .button.at_the_same_time:hover:after {
      width: 20rem;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
      border-bottom: .5rem solid $color-lightest;
      border-left: .5rem solid $color-lightest;
      transition: width 300ms cubic-bezier(0.07, 0.62, 0.61, 1), height 150ms 300ms cubic-bezier(0.07, 0.62, 0.61, 1);
    }
```

```html
<div class="action-buttons">
        <a class="button at_the_same_time click">Generate Forms</a>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <a class="button at_the_same_time click" name="10" data-slide="slide10">Sign Forms</a>   
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <a class="button at_the_same_time click" name="11" data-slide="slide11">Completed Forms</a>
      </div>
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
.button.at_the_same_time:active, 
 .button.at_the_same_time:focus 
 {
     border.5rem solid $color-lightest;
  }
```

Comment: :active should work? Can you show the code where you tried this?

Comment: you're missing the `:` after border in your :active CSS.  If you add that, it works just fine.

Comment: ah nice catch, but it still doesn't work.  thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you understand what `:active` is? It's not linked to the current state of your application. It's just an indicator of instantaneous click action.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple reasons actually made it not working. First of all there's a typo in your css

```
border.5rem solid $color-lightest;
```

will not work because you have a missing colon and space after border

```
border: .5rem solid $color-lightest;
```

And then you might wanna take a look at this : [Is an anchor tag without the href attribute safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292343/is-an-anchor-tag-without-the-href-attribute-safe)

Your actual `<a>` isn't a proper link, it's a placeholder hyperlink, therefore the browser reacts differently.

Adding just a `#` in the href makes it activable on click.

See jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h7jfxdqt/7/)