# Link to new page and open specific modal

Tags: php, html, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I am trying to link from my homepage to a page where I have Foundation Reveal modals that open up on a user click revealing a recipe.

I want to feature some recipes on my homepage and when a user clicks on one of the recipes on the homepage, I want it to open the recipes page and open the specific modal on the recipes page that goes with that recipe.

Here is my code on the homepage for the featured recipe:

```
<div class="content grid-x">
    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'recipes',
            'orderby'   => 'rand',
            'posts_per_page' => 3
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $counter = 0;
        if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); 
            global $post;
            $slug = $post->post_name; 
    ?>

    <a class="cell small-12 large-4 recipeCell" data-open="recipe-<?php echo $slug; ?>">
        <div class="cell text-left" >
            <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>"/>
            <div class="recipeTitle" data-sr><div class="doubleUnderline"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></div></div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <?php $counter++; endwhile; endif; ?>
</div>
```

And here is the code for the modal (I am using Foundation Reveal modals):

```
<div class="reveal recipeModal" id="recipe-<?php echo $slug; ?>"  style="background:url(<?php the_field('image'); ?>) center center;background-size: cover;" data-reveal>
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-x recipeDetails">
            <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>" class="printableImage" />
                <div class="cell small-12 doubleUnderline"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></div>
                    <h6 class="cell small-9 time">Start to Finish: <?php the_field('preparation_time'); ?></h6>
                    <h6 class="cell small-3 text-right servings">Servings: <?php the_field('servings'); ?></h6>
                    <div class="recipeInstructions">
                        <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#"><button class="button large printButton darkButton" style="margin:0;" onclick="window.print();return false;">Print Recipe</button></a>
                </div>   
        </div>   

        <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I am using "recipe-" + the post slug to create the ID for each recipe card so that I can associate it with the modal it needs to open. Is there a way to send that data to the recipe page and open that specific modal there rather than on the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

On your homepage, make sure your recipe  links include the recipe ID as a parameter in the URL. Right now your recipe  links are missing 'href'; are you loading pages with AJAX or something other than regular page loads? I believe data-attributes are only useful on a single page instance.

Ultimately you'd want the request URL to be something along these lines: `http://www.mywebsite.com/recipes/?recipe=34512`

Then on your recipes page, run a Javascript after page load, which will check the URL parameters and if a specific recipe exists in the request URL, then open the modal accordingly, otherwise just show the recipes page as-is. Ideally you have a custom template for the recipe page where you could put the JS.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url_string = window.location.href
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var recipeToLoad = url.searchParams.get("recipe");
    if(recipeToLoad) {
         jQuery('#recipeToLoad').foundation('reveal', 'open')});
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently the code I have is all on the homepage so since they are on the same page I didn't need to include the href but I was wanting to change it so that it linked to a different page. I will try this solution and let you know

Comment: Ok. You may piece together a working system not using href's, but it's really not advisable. Browsers, search spiders and people all expect URLs to be associated with <a> tags. How can I bookmark the link, or open it in a new tab? Anyone on an older browser, or with Javascript disabled, may have big problems using your site. [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292343/is-an-anchor-tag-without-the-href-attribute-safe).

Comment: Got it. Didn't think about that, I was just implementing the Foundation reveal code on what I had already in place. The JS you provided runs into an error that says "We're sorry, 'reveal' is not an available method for this element." I tried deleting it and it also says the "open" is not an available method either. Should I build the modals differently or is there a workaround to still use the foundation reveal?

Comment: I made a minor edit to that line (jQuery instead of $), try now. If there's still a problem, check how you're loading Foundation. Is it a Javascript loaded on every page? In the header or footer? Anyways I don't know much about Foundation. Good luck!