# How to make a radio button look like a toggle button

Tags: html, css, radio-button, radiobuttonlist, togglebutton

I want a group of radio buttons to look like a group of toggle buttons (but still function like radio buttons). It's not necessary that they look exactly like toggle buttons.

How can I do this only with CSS and HTML?

EDIT: I will be satisfied making the little circle disappear and changing the style when the button is checked/unchecked.

Comment: AFAIK styling radio buttons is very limited. You'll *probably* have to use JavaScript to accomplish this.

Comment: if you are willing to go outside the css/html req: http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/06/16/iphone-style-checkboxes.html

Comment: take a look to [segmented button](http://schinckel.net/2012/01/23/styling-radio-buttons-like-a-segmented-button/)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Depending on which browsers you aim to support, you could use the [`:checked` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked) selector in addition to hiding the radio buttons.

Using this HTML:

```html
<input type="radio" id="toggle-on" name="toggle" checked
><label for="toggle-on">On</label
><input type="radio" id="toggle-off" name="toggle"
><label for="toggle-off">Off</label>
```

You could use something like the following CSS:

```css
input[type="radio"].toggle {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label {
  /* Do something special with the selected state */
}
```

For instance, (to keep the custom CSS brief) if you were using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), you might add `class="btn"` to your `<label>` elements and style them appropriately to create a toggle that looks like:

[image: Bootstrap-aided radio toggle]

...which just requires the following additional CSS:

```
input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top,#969696,#727272);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 6px rgba(41, 41, 41, 0.2),
                    0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  cursor: default;
  color: #E6E6E6;
  border-color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.75);
}

input[type="radio"].toggle + label {
  width: 3em;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label.btn:hover {
  background-color: inherit;
  background-position: 0 0;
  transition: none;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle-left + label {
  border-right: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle-right + label {
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

I've included this as well as the extra fallback styles in a **[radio button toggle jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tms/uPv6X/)**. Note that `:checked` is only supported in IE 9, so this approach is limited to newer browsers.

However, if you need to support IE 8 and are willing to fall back on JavaScript*, you can hack in pseudo-support for `:checked` without too much difficulty (although you can just as easily set classes directly on the label at that point).

Using some quick and dirty jQuery code as **[an example of the workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/tms/DBZPh/)**:

```
$('.no-checkedselector').on('change', 'input[type="radio"].toggle', function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('input[name="' + this.name + '"].checked').removeClass('checked');
        $(this).addClass('checked');
        // Force IE 8 to update the sibling selector immediately by
        // toggling a class on a parent element
        $('.toggle-container').addClass('xyz').removeClass('xyz');
    }
});
$('.no-checkedselector input[type="radio"].toggle:checked').addClass('checked');
```

You can then make a few changes to the CSS to complete things:

```
input[type="radio"].toggle {
  /* IE 8 doesn't seem to like to update radio buttons that are display:none */
  position: absolute;
  left: -99em;
}

input[type="radio"].toggle:checked + label,
input[type="radio"].toggle.checked + label {
  /* Do something special with the selected state */
}
```

<sub>*If you're using Modernizr, you can use the [`:selector` test](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/441842) to help determine if you need the fallback. I called my test "checkedselector" in the example code, and the jQuery event handler is subsequently only set up when the test fails.</sub>

Answer (score 64):

Here's my version of that nice CSS solution JS Fiddle example posted above.

http://jsfiddle.net/496c9/

**HTML**

```
<div id="donate">
    <label class="blue"><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>$20</span></label>
    <label class="green"><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>$50</span></label>
    <label class="yellow"><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>$100</span></label>
    <label class="pink"><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>$500</span></label>
    <label class="purple"><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>$1000</span></label>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

#donate {
    margin:4px;

    float:left;
}

#donate label {
    float:left;
    width:170px;
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;

}

#donate label span {
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 32px;
    padding:13px 0px;
    display:block;
}

#donate label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

#donate input:checked + span {
    background-color:#404040;
    color:#F7F7F7;
}

#donate .yellow {
    background-color:#FFCC00;
    color:#333;
}

#donate .blue {
    background-color:#00BFFF;
    color:#333;
}

#donate .pink {
    background-color:#FF99FF;
    color:#333;
}

#donate .green {
    background-color:#A3D900;
    color:#333;
}
#donate .purple {
    background-color:#B399FF;
    color:#333;
}
```

Styled with coloured buttons :)

Comment: I tried to use your code, window scroll goes to top when a bottom button is clicked on e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/496c9/764/
can something be done about it?

Comment: Puneet - Check this for a possible answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252730/how-to-prevent-a-click-on-a-link-from-jumping-to-top-of-page-in-jquery

Comment: To avoid the scroll problem add the following to "#donate label" - display: block;position: relative;overflow: hidden;

Comment: old one but it seems that `visibility:hidden` can replace the `offscreen hack` i.e instead of ` top:-20px;` do `visibility:hidden`

Comment: Very nice solution for that problem! Thanks!

Comment: @oak you can even go as far as `display: none` and it will still work.

Answer (score 25):

### PURE CSS AND HTML (as asked) with ANIMATIONS! (and Checkboxes TOO!)

Example Image (**you can run the code below**):

[image: Toggle Buttons (Radio and Checkbox) in Pure CSS and HTML]

After looking for something really clean and straight forward, I ended up building this with ONE simple change from [another code](https://codepen.io/davidtaubmann/pen/BzKXMw) that was  built only thinking on checkboxes, so I tryed the funcionality for RADIOS and it worked too(!).

The CSS (SCSS) is fully from @mallendeo (as established on the JS credits), what I did was simply change the type of the input to RADIO, and gave the same name to all the radio switches.... and VOILA!! They deactivate automatically one to the other!!

Very clean, and as you asked it's only CSS and HTML!!

It is exactly what I was looking for since 3 days after trying and editing more than a dozen of options (which mostly requiered jQuery, or didn't allow labels, or even wheren't really compatible with current browsers). This one's got it all!

I'm obligated to include the code in here to allow you to see a working example, so:

```js
/** Toggle buttons
 * @mallendeo
 * forked @davidtaubmann
 * from https://codepen.io/mallendeo/pen/eLIiG
 */
```

```css
html, body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul, li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tg-list {
  text-align: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.tg-list-item {
  margin: 0 10px;;
}

h2 {
  color: #777;
}

h4 {
  color: #999;
}

.tgl {
  display: none;
}
.tgl, .tgl:after, .tgl:before, .tgl *, .tgl *:after, .tgl *:before, .tgl + .tgl-btn {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tgl::-moz-selection, .tgl:after::-moz-selection, .tgl:before::-moz-selection, .tgl *::-moz-selection, .tgl *:after::-moz-selection, .tgl *:before::-moz-selection, .tgl + .tgl-btn::-moz-selection {
  background: none;
}
.tgl::selection, .tgl:after::selection, .tgl:before::selection, .tgl *::selection, .tgl *:after::selection, .tgl *:before::selection, .tgl + .tgl-btn::selection {
  background: none;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn {
  outline: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 4em;
  height: 2em;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn:after, .tgl + .tgl-btn:before {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 0;
}
.tgl + .tgl-btn:before {
  display: none;
}
.tgl:checked + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 50%;
}

.tgl-light + .tgl-btn {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}
.tgl-light + .tgl-btn:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
.tgl-light:checked + .tgl-btn {
  background: #9FD6AE;
}

.tgl-ios + .tgl-btn {
  background: #fbfbfb;
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  border: 1px solid #e8eae9;
}
.tgl-ios + .tgl-btn:after {
  border-radius: 2em;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275), padding 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
  transition: left 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275), padding 0.3s ease, margin 0.3s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
.tgl-ios + .tgl-btn:hover:after {
  will-change: padding;
}
.tgl-ios + .tgl-btn:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2em #e8eae9;
}
.tgl-ios + .tgl-btn:active:after {
  padding-right: .8em;
}
.tgl-ios:checked + .tgl-btn {
  background: #86d993;
}
.tgl-ios:checked + .tgl-btn:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.tgl-ios:checked + .tgl-btn:active:after {
  margin-left: -.8em;
}

.tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
          transform: skew(-10deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #888;
}
.tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn:after, .tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn:before {
  -webkit-transform: skew(10deg);
          transform: skew(10deg);
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 100%;
  content: attr(data-tg-on);
}
.tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn:before {
  left: 0;
  content: attr(data-tg-off);
}
.tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn:active {
  background: #888;
}
.tgl-skewed + .tgl-btn:active:before {
  left: -10%;
}
.tgl-skewed:checked + .tgl-btn {
  background: #86d993;
}
.tgl-skewed:checked + .tgl-btn:before {
  left: -100%;
}
.tgl-skewed:checked + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 0;
}
.tgl-skewed:checked + .tgl-btn:active:after {
  left: 10%;
}

.tgl-flat + .tgl-btn {
  padding: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  background: #fff;
  border: 4px solid #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 2em;
}
.tgl-flat + .tgl-btn:after {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  content: "";
  border-radius: 1em;
}
.tgl-flat:checked + .tgl-btn {
  border: 4px solid #7FC6A6;
}
.tgl-flat:checked + .tgl-btn:after {
  left: 50%;
  background: #7FC6A6;
}

.tgl-flip + .tgl-btn {
  padding: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease;
  transition: all .2s ease;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-perspective: 100px;
          perspective: 100px;
}
.tgl-flip + .tgl-btn:after, .tgl-flip + .tgl-btn:before {
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s ease;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.tgl-flip + .tgl-btn:after {
  content: attr(data-tg-on);
  background: #02C66F;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.tgl-flip + .tgl-btn:before {
  background: #FF3A19;
  content: attr(data-tg-off);
}
.tgl-flip + .tgl-btn:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-20deg);
          transform: rotateY(-20deg);
}
.tgl-flip:checked + .tgl-btn:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.tgl-flip:checked + .tgl-btn:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0);
          transform: rotateY(0);
  left: 0;
  background: #7FC6A6;
}
.tgl-flip:checked + .tgl-btn:active:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(20deg);
          transform: rotateY(20deg);
}
```

```html
<h2>Toggle 'em</h2>
<ul class='tg-list'>
  <li class='tg-list-item'>
    <h3>Radios:</h3>
  </li>
  <li class='tg-list-item'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd1'>
      <h4>Light</h4>
    </label>
    <input class='tgl tgl-light' id='rd1' name='group' type='radio'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd1'></label>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd1'>
      <h4>Light</h4>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='tg-list-item'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd2'>
      <h4>iOS 7 (Disabled)</h4>
    </label>
    <input checked class='tgl tgl-ios' disabled id='rd2' name='group' type='radio'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd2'></label>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd2'>
      <h4>iOS 7 (Disabled)</h4>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='tg-list-item'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd3'>
      <h4>Skewed</h4>
    </label>
    <input class='tgl tgl-skewed' id='rd3' name='group' type='radio'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' data-tg-off='OFF' data-tg-on='ON' for='rd3'></label>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd3'>
      <h4>Skewed</h4>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='tg-list-item'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd4'>
      <h4>Flat</h4>
    </label>
    <input class='tgl tgl-flat' id='rd4' name='group' type='radio'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd4'></label>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd4'>
      <h4>Flat</h4>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='tg-list-item'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd5'>
      <h4>Flip</h4>
    </label>
    <input class='tgl tgl-flip' id='rd5' name='group' type='radio'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' data-tg-off='Nope' data-tg-on='Yeah!' for='rd5'></label>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='rd5'>
      <h4>Flip</h4>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class='tg-list'>
  <li class='tg-list-item'>
    <h3>Checkboxes:</h3>
  </li>
  <li class='tg-list-item'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb1'>
      <h4>Light</h4>
    </label>
    <input class='tgl tgl-light' id='cb1' type='checkbox'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb1'></label>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb1'>
      <h4>Light</h4>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='tg-list-item'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb2'>
      <h4>iOS 7</h4>
    </label>
    <input class='tgl tgl-ios' id='cb2' type='checkbox'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb2'></label>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb2'>
      <h4>iOS 7</h4>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='tg-list-item'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb3'>
      <h4>Skewed</h4>
    </label>
    <input class='tgl tgl-skewed' id='cb3' type='checkbox'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' data-tg-off='OFF' data-tg-on='ON' for='cb3'></label>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb3'>
      <h4>Skewed</h4>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='tg-list-item'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb4'>
      <h4>Flat</h4>
    </label>
    <input class='tgl tgl-flat' id='cb4' type='checkbox'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb4'></label>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb4'>
      <h4>Flat</h4>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class='tg-list-item'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb5'>
      <h4>Flip</h4>
    </label>
    <input class='tgl tgl-flip' id='cb5' type='checkbox'>
    <label class='tgl-btn' data-tg-off='Nope' data-tg-on='Yeah!' for='cb5'></label>
    <label class='tgl-btn' for='cb5'>
      <h4>Flip</h4>
    </label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you run the snippet, you'll see I leave the iOS radio checked and disabled, so you can watch how it is also affected when activating another one. I also included 2 labels for each radio, one before and one after. The copy of the original code to show the working checkboxes in the same window is also included.

Comment: Impressed I am. Focus you did. :)

Answer (score 18):

Here is the solution that works for all browsers (also IE7 and IE8; didn't check for IE6):

http://jsfiddle.net/RkvAP/230/

**HTML**

```
<div class="toggle">
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>On</span></label>    
</div>
<div class="toggle">
    <label><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>Off</span></label>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('label').click(function(){
    $(this).children('span').addClass('input-checked');
    $(this).parent('.toggle').siblings('.toggle').children('label').children('span').removeClass('input-checked');
});
```

**CSS**

```css
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

.toggle {
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
}

.toggle label {
    float:left;
    width:2.0em;
}

.toggle label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 0px;
    display:block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

.toggle .input-checked /*, .bounds input:checked + span works for firefox and ie9 but breaks js for ie8(ONLY) */ {
    background-color:#404040;
    color:#F7F7F7;
}
```

Makes use of minimal JS (jQuery, two lines).

Comment: minus one, because question specified clearly: only CSS and HTML

Comment: looks that for `.toggle label input` in Chrome this also works  `.toggle label input { display:none }`

Comment: The solution was made to support IE8 and IE7. No need for that now, I guess :-)

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Michal B. answer. If you use bootstrap..

```css
label.btn {
  padding: 0;
}

label.btn input {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

label.btn span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  display: block;
}

label.btn input:checked+span {
  background-color: rgb(80, 110, 228);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary"><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>One</span></label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary"><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>Two</span></label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary"><input type="radio" name="toggle"><span>Three</span></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually hide the real radio buttons with CSS (or make them into individual hidden inputs), put in the imagery I want (you could use an unordered list and apply your styles to the li element) and then use click events to toggle the inputs. That approach also means you can keep things accessible for users who aren't on a normal web browser-- just hide your ul by default and show the radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but since I was just looking to do this, I thought I would post what I ended up with.  Because I am using Bootstrap, I went with a Bootstrap option.

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidType" runat="server" />
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Selection type" id="divType">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BtnType" data-value="1">Food</button>                        
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BtnType" data-value="2">Drink</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divType button').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $('#<%= hidType.ClientID%>').val($(this).data('value'));
        //alert($(this).data('value'));             
    });
});
```

I chose to store the value in a hidden field so that it would be easy for me to get the value server-side.

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#divType button').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        $('#<%= hidType.ClientID%>').val($(this).data('value'));
        //alert($(this).data('value'));             
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hidType" runat="server" />
        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Selection type" id="divType">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BtnType" data-value="1">Food</button>                        
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default BtnType" data-value="2">Drink</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Your anwsering on a question nearly 10 years old. Besides that, your anwser seems to a a C&P answer with unecessary lines for the issue. Then it does not fullfill what the OP actually wants (you sue no radio buttons, for which btw you don't need JS at all). Last but not least, you should know, that your snippet already outputs a JS parsing error. As such I consider your anwser to be "low quality" and spam.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't wanted to do that, It worked in localhost actually...

Answer (score -4):

HTML:

```
<div>
    <label> <input type="radio" name="toggle"> On </label>
    <label> Off <input type="radio" name="toggle"> </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { overflow:auto; border:1px solid #ccc; width:100px; }
label { float:left; padding:3px 0; width:50px; text-align:center; }
input { vertical-align:-2px; }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/scymE/1/

Comment: This doesn't make the little circle disappear at all and therefore does not answer the question