# Button Group use JQuery change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, buttongroup

I have a button group an with on.click function it is working. but not with on.change.

```
            <div class="ui buttons">
                <button class="ui button">Value 1</button>
                <button class="ui button">Value 2</button>
                <button class="ui button">Value 3</button>
            </div>
```

And here is my function

```
$('.ui.button').on('click change', function(){
    alert(...)
});
```

When i use this without click, it's not working.

Comment: and how would onchange event be triggered?

Comment: button don't have onchange event!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, buttons don't have an on change event, but if you wanted to use something with both onclick and onchange events, might I suggest a [radio](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio) button?

Comment: okay.. yes i have changed it to radio. I tried it with buttonset because it has a better look. I am working with semantic-ui

Comment: @WolfgangMüller You can style radio buttons to look like a button, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can style radio buttons to look like a normal button.

See [**POST**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12524483/2813224)

```css
body { font: 400 16px/1.45 "Palatino Linotype"; }
.buttons {
  margin: 4px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 12px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
.buttons .button {
  float: left;
  width: 70px;
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #111;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #0FF;
  overflow: auto;
}
.buttons .button span {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 4px 0px;
  display: block;
}
.buttons .button .check {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
}
.buttons .check:checked + span {
  background-color: #0FF;
  color: #111;
  border: 1px solid #0FF;
}
.buttons .button {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #0FF;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="ui buttons">
  <label class="ui button">
    <input type="radio" class="check" name="toggle"><span>Value 1</span>
  </label>
  <label class="ui button">
    <input type="radio" class="check" name="toggle"><span>Value 2</span>
  </label>
  <label class="ui button">
    <input type="radio" class="check" name="toggle"><span>Value 3</span>
  </label>
</fieldset>
```