# How do I give radio-buttons in a form a custom look?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Code:

```html
<label class="form__label" for="urgency">Urgency</label>

            <input class="form__input no-input-animation" id="urgency" name="urgency" type="radio" required>
                <div class="urgency-text critical">Critical</div>
                <div class="urgency-text high">High</div>
                <div class="urgency-text medium">Medium</div>
                <div class="urgency-text low">Low</div>
```

This shows one radio button with each urgency div as one option collectively. I can understand why.

I would like my buttons to have no radio checkbox and each of the divs be its own option, with a `value` attribute.

EXAMPLE:

---

**Choose Status**:

[ Available ] [ Idle ] [ Do Not Disturb ]

---

Each item in square brackets `[]` is clickable and has it's own value attribute, e.g. `available`

How do I make this work inside a **form**?

Thanks.

Comment: " I would like my buttons to have no radio checkbox and each of the divs be its own option, with a value attribute. "

Please explain this line, this is little bit confusing for me.

Comment: @PrabeshGouli added an example.

Comment: You want the options ('critical', 'high', 'medium' and 'low) to appear as mutually-exclusive buttons? (In which case you may be duplicating this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523735/how-to-make-a-radio-button-look-like-a-toggle-button)

Comment: what if you use `button` rather than `div`, `button` has its own value attribute and handle state too.

Sorry again but I am still confused about what you actually need.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to refer to this as an example. I believe this is exactly what you're looking for.

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="segmented-control" style="width: 100%; color: #5FBAAC">
    <input type="radio" name="sc-1-1" id="sc-1-1-1">
    <input type="radio" name="sc-1-1" id="sc-1-1-2">
    <input type="radio" name="sc-1-1" id="sc-1-1-3" checked>

    <label for="sc-1-1-1" data-value="High">High</label>
    <label for="sc-1-1-2" data-value="Medium">Medium</label>
    <label for="sc-1-1-3" data-value="Low">Low</label>
  </div>
```

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/adil-bub/pen/rNeNBXq) **<--** Is what youre looking for.

Visit [this blog](https://blog.prototypr.io/implementing-dropdown-alternatives-568c6d3464ed) for more information.