# How to stop a function when another function starts in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I have 2 buttons with respective functions: `linemaker` and `circlemaker`.

In `linemaker` I have 3 `eventlisteners`: `mousedown`, `mousemove`, and `mouseup`. This is so I can draw on the canvas.

In `circlemaker` I have 1 `eventlistener`: `click`. So I take a radius input from the user and with a click, they can make circles on the canvas.

But if they click both buttons, after they draw, there will be a circle at the end of the line. I want to stop this from happening, so if they click the circle button, the line button's function will stop. And vice versa.

Is there a way to do this? I don't use any `setTimeout` so I don't think I can use `clearTimeout` here.

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't provide code, I will propose a way to draw lines and circles. First of all, I would use radio buttons for the selection of line or circle. You can apply CSS to give those a [button look-n-feel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523735/how-to-make-a-radio-button-look-like-a-toggle-button) if you really want to.

Then on the mousedown event, read out which radiobutton is checked.

On mousemove, just consider that the shape (line or circle) could be finished (no mouseup listener is needed). As long as another mousemove event follows, just adapt the last drawn shape.

For a circle, it seems more intuitive to not ask for a radius input, but use the mousemove event to determine the radius of the circle. This way the interface is very similar for drawing lines and circles, as two points can be used to define a line and to define a circle.

Here is a tiny demo:

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let items = [];

function distance(a, b) {
    return Math.sqrt((b.x-a.x)**2 + (b.y-a.y)**2);
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (let {itemType, start, end} of items) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        if (itemType == "line") {
            ctx.moveTo(start.x, start.y);
            ctx.lineTo(end.x, end.y);
        } else {
            ctx.arc(start.x, start.y, distance(start, end), 0, 2*Math.PI);
        }
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function cursorPoint(e) {
    return { x: e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft, y: e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop };
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    let itemType = document.querySelector("[name='shape']:checked").value;
    items.push({itemType, start: cursorPoint(e), end: cursorPoint(e)});
    draw();
});

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    if (e.buttons === 0) return;
    items[items.length-1].end = cursorPoint(e);
    draw();
});
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<br><input type="radio" name="shape" value="line" checked>Line
<br><input type="radio" name="shape" value="circle">Circle
```

Answer (score 0):

Make variables for this

```
let lineDrawing = false
let circleDrawing = false
```

Whenever the line function is called, check to make sure `circleDrawing === false` before  setting `lineDrawing = true` and running the line drawing code. When the user stops drawing, set `lineDrawing = false`

Whenever the circle function is called, check to make sure `lineDrawing === false` before  setting `circleDrawing = true` and running the circle drawing code. When the user stops drawing, set `circleDrawing = false`