# jquery # scrolls to top

Tags: jquery, href

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avoid window jump to top when clicking #-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240554/avoid-window-jump-to-top-when-clicking-links)

On my site I have links that I click and jquery handles an event for them. The links are simple, eg:

```
<a href=# class=bleh>click</a>
```

The problem is, I click a link such as that, it scrolls to the top of the page (probably because of the #).

Is there any way to make the page not scroll up at all and just stay put?

I understand I dont need the href tag, but I want it to appear as a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use this, slightly longer but works

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="bleh">click</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling the click default behavior on links with `href="#"`.

```
$('[href="#"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) which prevents the default action of the click event:

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
$('.bleh').click(function(eve){
   eve.preventDefault()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.bleh').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing 'void' after the '#' should stop the scrolling and still allow the event to fire.

```
<a href=#void class=bleh>click</a>
```

Comment: if you don't have an element with `id="void"` artibute: yes, otherwise no