# Using jQuery to add an additional parameter to the current URL without reloading the page?

Tags: jquery

A client has a page on their website with a list of staff. When a user clicks on a name, then using jQuery, a bio section on the right will fade out of the current bio, and fade in with the selected bio.

This is fine, but the issue is that they can't link to specific bio's, as it's all under the same URL.

I have the jQuery to retrieve a parameter from the URL, and show the correct bio on page load, but the problem is that I need to change/add this parameter on each staff name click, ready to be copied and pasted.

The list of the links looks like this:

```
<ul class="team_list">
    <li><a href="#">Staff Name 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Staff Name 2</a></li>     
    <li><a href="#">Staff Name 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to do this without reloading any pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a URL fragment, aka a hash-value:

```
<ul class="team_list">
    <li><a href="#name1">Staff Name 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#name2">Staff Name 2</a></li>     
    <li><a href="#name3">Staff Name 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

You can then use `window.location.hash` on load of the page to retrieve the value and display the right bio as needed.

Comment: Not only on load of the page, but on the actual click handler as well ;)

Comment: Hadn't thought of this method before. Much simpler!

Comment: That too, although I assumed the OP already has a click handler in place for that.

Comment: Had to remove the `return false;` from the click handler and it's working. Many thanks

Comment: Found a problem with this, is that if there is an ID on the page with the same name as the hash value, then the page jumps.

Comment: In the click handler, use `preventDefault()` on the `event` raised: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252730/how-to-prevent-a-click-on-a-link-from-jumping-to-top-of-page-in-jquery