# JavaScript - Page goes back to the top after clicking on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This makes it anoying because you have to scroll back down to where you were. Can someone tell me what this behavior is.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Html

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">School Area</a>
<div id="foo" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent a click on a '#' link from jumping to top of page in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252730/how-to-prevent-a-click-on-a-link-from-jumping-to-top-of-page-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `href="#"` tells the browser to jump to the top of the page when the link is clicked.

You can prevent that default action by returning `false` from your `onclick` attribute handler:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');return false;">School Area</a>
```

---

But as you're using jQuery, consider attaching that event handler dynamically (or even using event delegation), and then use `preventDefault`:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-vis" data-visibility="foo">School Area</a>
```

then here's a delegated handler:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".toggle-vis", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    toggle_visibility(this.getAttribute("data-visibility"));
});
```

note how the `data-visibility` attribute controls what we toggle.

---

You'll get people telling you to change this line:

```
toggle_visibility(this.getAttribute("data-visibility"));
```

to

```
// Only do this if you understand what `data` does
toggle_visibility($(this).data("visibility"));
```

but [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) **is not** just an accessor for `data-*` elements, it does more (and less) than that. If you don't need the features that work sets up, there's no need to wrap the element in a jQuery instance and call `data.` But if you prefer More jQuery™:

```
toggle_visibility($(this).attr("data-visibility"));
```

also works.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of `#`. Add this to `href`:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Default behavior of [**`<a>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) elements is `navigation/redirection`

Use [**`e.preventDefault()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent default action

```js
function toggle_visibility(e, id) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility(event,'foo');">School Area</a>
<div id="foo" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behaviour of this element you can use

Use `javascript:void(0)` in `href` to avoid its behaviour.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">School Area</a>
```

**OR**

use `preventDefault()` in function to prevent its default behavior to execute.

```
function toggle_visibility(e, id) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also change from

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">School Area</a>
```

to

```
<a style="cursor:pointer;text-decoration:underline;color:blue"
  onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');"
>School Area</a>
```