# page seems to scroll when link clicked at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

whenever I click an anchor element it's being scrolled to the top of the page in various browsers such as firefox, safari, and IE. But the page is not scrolled in chrome. Used various approaches such as preventDefault(), return false and also using "#/" in href. But none of them seems to work. It would be great if someone could help me with this issue.
Followed all the approaches mentioned in this page:
[How to prevent a click on a '#' link from jumping to top of page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252730/how-to-prevent-a-click-on-a-link-from-jumping-to-top-of-page) .

Here is my code

```
function Scrolldown() {
  window.location.hash = "#relationships-card";
}

const attachLink = (onClick, relationship, maybeId) => (
  <a
    href="#relationship-card"
    aria-label="Attach Relationship"
    className="hidden-print"
    onClick={() => {
      onClick(relationship, maybeId);
      Scrolldown();
    }}
  >
    &nbsp;Attach
  </a>
);
```

Comment: Provide a working plunker

Comment: Where is the logic to stop scrolling? is it in `onClick(relationship, maybeId)`? If so, can you post the code here?

Comment: @ibex window.location.hash = "#relationships-card"; I'm using this to manually enforce the scroll to that particular card