# LinkButton in gridview to open modal at the position the scroll is in but it refreshes page back to the top and opens modal and

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, bootstrap-modal, postback

I have a gridview that has a template field which contains a link button. When the user clicks on this link button I am calling an OnClick event DisplayModal which runs a method to get the dynamic values to from the database to a datatable to bind to the modal gridview. This method runs ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript to call jquery function openModal() which shows the modal. This works fine.

I have three gridviews on the page. When i scroll down the second gridview and click on the link button the modal opens with the correct values on the modal but it refreshes the page so the scrollbar is back at the top rather than where i clicked on the gridview and then opens the modal.

I want to prevent it from refreshing the page. I have got an update panel around the gridview and PostBackTrigger tag after the modal.

```
    protected void DisplayModal(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(((sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow).RowIndex);
    GridViewRow row = gvTeamCAOTDashboard.Rows[rowIndex];

    row.Focus();

    MeasurecodeClicked = (row.FindControl("lnkBtnEdit") as LinkButton).Text;
    GetKPICriteria(MeasurecodeClicked); //calls sql method to bind data

    H1.InnerText = "KPI Criteria - " + MeasurecodeClicked;

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);

}
  function openModal() {

        $("#myModal").modal('show');

    }

<div class="table-responsive">
                   <asp:updatepanel id="Updatepanel1" runat="server">
               <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:GridView ID="gvTeamCAOTDashboard" class="table table-bordered" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="ControlDesc" runat="server" CellPadding="0" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvTeamCAOTDashboard_RowDataBound" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
               <Columns>


                      <asp:BoundField DataField="IsWorkingDay" HeaderText="IsWorkingDay" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="IsWorkingDay" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide"  >
                          <ItemStyle CssClass="Hide" />
                 </asp:BoundField>



                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=""  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center" > 
                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnEdit"  ForeColor="Black" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MeasureCode") %>' 
                            OnClick="DisplayModal" ></asp:LinkButton>

                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>




                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="TotalCases" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center" ControlStyle-ForeColor="Black">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:HyperLink ID="TotalCases"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TotalCases") %>' />
                           </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Target" HeaderText="Standard" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="Target" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center" >
                           <HeaderStyle />
                        </asp:BoundField>

                   <asp:BoundField DataField="AvgDaysTaken" HeaderText="Average" ReadOnly="true" SortExpression="AvgDaysTaken" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center" >
                           <HeaderStyle />
                        </asp:BoundField>

               </Columns>
           </asp:GridView>


                                  <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="myModalTeam" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" runat="server" id="H1"></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <asp:GridView ID="gvModalTeam" runat="server">


                                </asp:GridView>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="closebutton" runat="server" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



                </ContentTemplate>
                  <Triggers >
      <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="gvTeamCAOTDashboard"  />
</Triggers>

            </asp:updatepanel> 

           </div>
```

Comment: should you try using e.PreventDefault in **openModal()** function ?!

Comment: function openModal() {
     
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
        e.preventdefault();
     
    }

This doesnt work - still refreshes page. Is this correct?

Comment: could you please swap two lines and put it at the beginning ?

Comment: It now doesnt show the modal at all

Answer (score 0):

if you inspect the generated html in your browser you can find an  tag with the id of **lnkBtnEdit** and attribute of "href="#". As it is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3252730/7855321) you can find similar issue.

try to add href="#/" to the linkbutton

Comment: The problem with this is I need to call the DisplayModal method as it has some sql connection to get the data binded to the gridview gvModalTeam in the modal body. This will just open a modal with no data inside. Currently I use the onclick to call the asp method

Comment: Also the <a> tag doesnt have the property Text to assign the value Text='<%# Eval("MeasureCode") %>'

Comment: You did not mention about the restrictions. The code updated. Could you try adding **href="#/"** manually.

Comment: It does not call the onclick method (modal does not appear) but the URL is http://localhost:63705/Dashboard.aspx#/

            
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnEdit" href="#/"  ForeColor="Black" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MeasureCode") %>' 
                            OnClick="DisplayModalTeam" ></asp:LinkButton>

Comment: Updated code for DisplayModal c# method in question - added row.Focus() still doesnt work