# How to prevent scroll to top while clicking on anchor (href="ID")

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, slider

I'm trying to create a slider with 6 images.
I've used 6 anchors. Whenever user clicks on any anchor slider image will be change accordingly and will show that particular anchor's image but the problem I'm facing is whenever user clicks on anchor, my slider move to the top of the screen because I've used ID of the images as anchor's href

Any kind of help will be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent a click on a '#' link from jumping to top of page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252730/how-to-prevent-a-click-on-a-link-from-jumping-to-top-of-page)

Comment: Any kind of code will be appreciated aswell... give us the relevant html part

Comment: Sorry for bad writing I'm still learning!

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault();` to stop the default action

Comment: event.preventDefault(); it also disables my click functionality. You can visit my site to get the clue. 
worthitapp[dot]com 
iphone slider with text around it.