# Get the link form a href using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, href

Using jQuery how could I obtain the link inside this `a` tag?

```
<a title="Rainham Pizza and Kebab" href="/rainham-pizza" class="restsRestStatus restPageLink  restsStatusOpens"><b>Pre-order</b><span>Opens         16:00       </span></a>
```

I have tried using:

```
jQuery("a.restsRestStatusrestPageLinkrestsStatusOpens").html();
```

Comment: `jQuery("a.restsRestStatus").attr('href')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345427/jquery-set-and-get-href

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720970/jquery-hyperlinks-href-value

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery set and get href](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345427/jquery-set-and-get-href)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a.restsRestStatus.restPageLink.restsStatusOpens").attr("href");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as shown :-

```
var url = $('a.restsRestStatus').attr('href');
alert(url);
```

OR

```
var url = $("a.restsRestStatus.restPageLink.restsStatusOpens").attr("href");
alert(url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.attr()` in jquery

```
("a.restsRestStatus.restPageLink.restsStatusOpens").attr("href")
```

Comment: @satpal Thanks for pointing it. I just copied the selector from the question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var link = $('a.restPageLink').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
href = $('a').attr("href");
alert(href);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
var link =$(element).attr("href");
```

Answer (score 0):

use prop() over attr() in the majority of cases.

prop() is the current state of the input element, attr() is the default value.

prop() can contain things of different types, attr() can only contain strings

```
var url = $('a.restsRestStatus ').prop('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
var href = $(this).attr('href');
```