# How do I make an empty href="" unclickable?

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, href, liquid

I'm building a theme with html/css and liquid. The user can determine if a image should have an url or not. That's pretty easy to achieve with:

```
<a href="{{ klant_logo.logo_url }}" target="{{ klant_logo.nieuw_tabblad }}" > <img src="{{klant_logo.logo_klant.src | img_url: 500, quality: 70 }}" alt="logo"/></a>
```

BUT, when the user doesn't add a url, the above code generates this as HTML  which is still clickable and navigates to the top of the page (like with href="#">.

Is there a way (HTML, Jquery, i don't know) to make href="" only clickable if it has an actual url between the brackets?

**EDIT**: thanks for the quick reply's! This dit the trick:

```
{% if klant_logo.logo_url != "" %}
  <a href="{{ klant_logo.logo_url }}" target="{{ klant_logo.nieuw_tabblad }}" > <img src="{{klant_logo.logo_klant.src | img_url: 500, quality: 70 }}" alt="logo"/></a>
{% else %}
  <img src="{{klant_logo.logo_klant.src | img_url: 500, quality: 70 }}" alt="logo"/>{% endif %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to make an HTML anchor tag not clickable/linkable using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727659/is-it-possible-to-make-an-html-anchor-tag-not-clickable-linkable-using-css)

Comment: @zyd thanks, never found that one after searching for half an hour... Fixed it myself though :) Thanks again for the help!

Comment: that is an interesting solution you came up with, I like it!  Simple and explicit

Answer (score 1):

You can have a CSS class that makes certain links unavailable:

```
.inactiveLink {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
<a href="{{ klant_logo.logo_url }}" class="{{klant_logo.logo_url ? 'inactiveLink' : '' }}" />
```

Comment: Basically this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727659/is-it-possible-to-make-an-html-anchor-tag-not-clickable-linkable-using-css

Comment: @dustytrash thx! That seems to work :) But I found an other approach as well a minute ago (I was to quick to start asking on stack...) with some variables that worked as well!

Answer (score 1):

The better logic would be to check the user entered value if its blank or null.

Also you might like to refer : [jQuery hyperlinks - href value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720970/jquery-hyperlinks-href-value/721021#721021)